# check if sku not in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$file_handle = fopen("/var.../test.csv","r");
$file_count = 0;

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $fieldval = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $val1 = $fieldval[1];
    $val2 = $fieldval[7];
    echo $product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($val1);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    if($file_count>0) {
        $_product->setData('custAttr', $val2);
        $_product->save();
    }

    //echo $fieldval[1].$fieldval[7]."<br>";

    $file_count++;

}
fclose($file_handle);
```

In the above code, i read values from csv and update customatrribute. Everything is fine when the skus in excel is same as that of magento site.
But somehow the cron is not working when the sku is different. Could anyone help me how to check if sku not exist in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo $product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($val1);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

if($file_count>0) {
    $_product->setData('custAttr', $val2);
    $_product->save();
}
```

with

```
echo $product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($val1);
if ($product_id) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    if($file_count>0) {
         $_product->setData('custAttr', $val2);
         $_product->save();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your quick info..
the situation is excel contain "test123" sku and this sku is not there in magento. So the cron stops there. so i need to check wether test123 is there in magento. If there, then save value. is this possble?

Comment: the code I posted should do what you want. If the call to `getIdBySku` returns null then the line is skipped.. If it's not null then the product should be updated

Comment: sorry marius.. thanks..it worked..cheers... :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `if($file_count>0) {` to `if(($file_count > 0) && $_product) {` and you should be good to go.

What this does is that it avoids the update if the product object is not found and returns null.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.. but the situation is different. please see below comment. Thanks again